# Ubuntu 18.04 wifi and USB mouse lag/freeze

Tags: 18.04, usb, mouse

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Acer Laptop and got a problem. 
After starting Ubuntu and working a while my wifi gets unstable and sometimes stops. 
Also, at the same time my USB mouse starts showing a freeze, or call it a "lag". 
My touchpad shows no issues.

When restarting Ubuntu the problem is gone, but after a while they always come back.

I followed the steps in this tutorial to solve the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qnCG3IOOvE

It worked for a day or two, but now I got the problem back.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!